# Получить список пользователей в rosters (Smack)

Tags: java, android, xmpp

Использую `Smack` для обмена сообщениями по `xmpp`, на сервере `OpenFire` создала двух пользователей, создала группу `Friends` и добавила этих пользователей в данную группу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь на телефоне хочу получить список пользователей в `Roster`, для этого использую такой код:

```
               Roster roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(connection);
                Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
                Presence presence;
  for(RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                    presence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());
                    Log.e("Users in roster ", entry.getUser());
                    Log.e("Name of user in roster ", presence.getType().name());
                    Log.e("Status in roster", presence.getStatus());
                }
```

Получаю размер `entries` ноль. Соответственно в лог не выводится имя пользователей, которые находятся в `roster`. Почему размер `roster` равен нулю? Как получить пользователей, которые находятся в `roster`? 
Оба юзера находятся в онлайне. Я могу отправлять сообщению юзеру (по этому проблемы с connection исключаю).

Так же хочу добавить, что в самом `OpenFire` в разделе `roster` я вижу пользователя, который находится в `roster`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в конфиге сервака включен `mod_roster`?

Comment: @Suvitruf mod_roster - это плагин? Если это плагин, то я не вижу его на официальном сайте OpenFire.

Comment: Моя ошибка. С ejabberd перепутал.

Comment: А при подключении к одному из публичных серверов происходит аналогичная ситуация?

Answer (score 0):

Создание пользователей **на сервере** и добавление этих пользователей в некоторую группу не влечет за собой изменение ростеров этих пользователей.

Создание пользователя на сервере – это, формально говоря, просто добавление пары логин/пароль в БД, после которого пользователь может залогиниться с этой связкой на этом сервере.

Вам же нужно добавить контакт в ростер определенного пользователя. Точно не знаю, можно ли редактировать ростер определенного пользователя средствами OpenFire (но скорее всего можно), но можно просто залогиниться с клиента (например, с Xabber) под определенным пользователем и средствами клиента добавить в ростер залогиненного пользователя контакты.

После этой процедуры ростер пользователя изменится, и, скорее всего, Вы увидите добавленные контакты.